# How to create multiple scatter plots in SPSS arranged in a table like format?

Tags: data-visualization, spss

I have seen many reports which include (say) 6 scatter plots in one big table like format. Each scatter plot shows the relationship between two different variables. For example, one may show the relationship between income and expenditure and another may show the relationship between mortgage payment and holiday taken. All scatter plots are neatly 'tucked' together.

My question: **How do you create multiple scatter plots in SPSS?**

Also, the scatter plot that I have drawn in SPSS/PASW has 0.00 on the x-axis and this is repeated on the y-axis in the left hand corner where the two axes meet. Should this be only one 0.00 (like in all other graph forms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I'd never seen an SPSS  equivalent of R commands like `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` which enable creation of a grid like structure for multiple plots. **UPDATE:** But As @Andy W notes it sounds like there are options for doing this using SPSS GPL ([see pdf 4.4mb](http://www.hanken.fi/student/media/3618/gplreferenceguide.pdf)).
- SPSS does have scatterplot matrices, but that's for looking at all possible bivariate relatinships between a set of variables, whereas it sounds like you want to produce a grid of arbitrary scatter plots.
- One option would be to export the graphics from SPSS and use other software to arrange the graphics in the grid like structure. This could be word processing software or graphics software.

Comment: Just a caveat: While I've never seen such a feature, and several years back I used to be a regular SPSS user, there might be features that I'm not aware of.

Comment: There is a feature in the GPL language to do essentially what the `layout` command in R does. Check out the `GPL Reference Guide` that comes with the software for some examples. IMO it is much more difficult to work with than either `par` or `layout` in R though (but the small multiples ttnphns noted do work very well).

Answer (score 3):

You could do panel scatterplots in SPSS with variables not fully arbitrary but with units comparable. One example is below. I had 2 continuous standard normal variables NORMAL1 and NORMAL2 and 2 integer (1 through 5) variables INTEGER1 and INTEGER2. Units are comparable between the first two and between the second two. I plotted 4 scatterplots: INTEGER1xNORMAL1, INTEGER2xNORMAL1, INTEGER1xNORMAL2, INTEGER2xNORMAL2. It was plotted in Interactive Graphs - Scatterplot menu. If that's what you want ask me for details.

[image]

Comment: I believe the interactive graphing feature was discontinued with SPSS 17.

Comment: @rolando2, it doesn't really matter. Small multiples like this can be accomplished in pretty much any of the current graphing facilities (either through the GUI or syntax). See the `/PANEL` subcommand for `GRAPH`.

Comment: @rolando2, Interactive graphs are still there. The only difference is that they've lost their old looks and editing options; looks and editor is the same as in regular graphs now. Interactive graphs are great, for me, because they support creating categories out of variables (items) - just what I did above.

Answer (score 0):

[image]**This will create a dual axis chart!**

```spss
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.

* Chart Builder.

GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Weekof 
    MEAN(SearchVisitsPaidBranded)[name="MEAN_SearchVisitsPaidBranded"] 
    MEAN(DirectVisits)[name="MEAN_DirectVisits"] MISSING=LISTWISE 

REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.

BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: Weekof=col(source(s), name("Weekof"), unit.category())
  DATA: MEAN_SearchVisitsPaidBranded=col(source(s), 


name("MEAN_SearchVisitsPaidBranded"))
  DATA: MEAN_DirectVisits=col(source(s), name("MEAN_DirectVisits"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Weekof"))
  GUIDE: axis(scale(y1), label("Mean Search Visits (Paid Branded)"), 

color(color."3E58AC"))
  GUIDE: axis(scale(y2), label("Mean Direct Visits "), color(color."2EB848"), 

opposite())
  SCALE: y1 = linear(dim(2), include(0))
  SCALE: y2 = linear(dim(2), include(0))
  ELEMENT: line(position(Weekof*MEAN_SearchVisitsPaidBranded), missing.wings(), 
    color.interior(color."3E58AC"), scale(y1))
  ELEMENT: line(position(Weekof*MEAN_DirectVisits), missing.wings(), 
    color.interior(color."2EB848"), scale(y2))

END GPL.
```

Comment: This is interesting, but it doesn't seem to be *how to create a **scatterplot matrix***.

Comment: I agree with @gung, this does not appear to address the question.